# How to combine row with column headings?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataset which, simplified, looks something like this:

| Year | Name | January | February | March | April | May | Street |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | Bob |  | $100 | $197 | $124 | $100 | ABC |
| 2000 | Abe | $100 | $100 | $117 | $123 | $100 | ABC |
| 2001 | Bob | $100 | $100 | $197 | $103 | $150 | DEF |
| 2001 | Abe | $140 | $100 | $127 | $526 | $123 | ABC |
| 2002 | Abe | $100 | $100 | $198 | $102 | $101 | DEF |
| 2002 | Bob | $102 | $110 |  |  |  | ABC |
| 2003 | Carly | $100 | $100 | $197 |  |  | ABC |

I am trying to combine this data so that each person has one line, with the goal of counting and graphing how many months they paid  in a row.

I was thinking of trying to recode the data so that each person gets their own row, with a timeline of how much they paid by year and season, with column names like this, but I am having trouble figuring out how to do that.

| Name | 2000 January | 2000 February | 2000 March | 2000 April | 2000 May | 2001 January | 2001 February | 2001 March | 2001 April | 2001 May | 2002 January | 2002 February | 2002 March | 2002 April | 2002 May | Street |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Is there a way to condense variables in this way somehow?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pivot_wider` from `{tidyr}` will achieve this. Calling your dataframe `yeardata`, you can do the following:

```
selectmonths <- c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May")

result <- yeardata %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Year", values_from = selectmonths)
```